# How to divide and multiply Ansible facts queried by json_query?

Tags: automation, ansible, yaml, json-query

```
"{{ ansible_facts | json_query('mounts[*].size_available') }} / {{ ansible_facts | json_query('mounts[*].size_total') }} * 100"
```

I am trying to get size available and divide it by size total and Multiply it by 100 to give me the percentage disc usage. This current code gives me the output something like this:

> "msg": "[238273] / [483298433] * 100"

It completely ignores the `/` and the `*`.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Because you are outside of the Jinja expression, so it is returned as a simple string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*json_query* is not needed. Simply *map* the attributes, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (item.0 / item.1 * 100)|round }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ ansible_mounts|map(attribute='size_available')|list }}"
        - "{{ ansible_mounts|map(attribute='size_total')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=[2085240832, 41015336960]) => 
  msg: '5.0'
ok: [localhost] => (item=[30278656, 100663296]) => 
  msg: '30.0'
ok: [localhost] => (item=[21565116416, 109899771904]) => 
  msg: '20.0'
```

---

A simpler option is to iterate the list of mounts, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (item.size_available / item.size_total * 100)|round }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.mount }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=/) => 
  msg: '5.0'
ok: [localhost] => (item=/boot/efi) => 
  msg: '30.0'
ok: [localhost] => (item=/export) => 
  msg: '20.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need your math operator to be inside the [Jinja expression `{{ ... }}`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#expressions).

Moreover, since you are getting `[238273]` and `[483298433]` your JMESPath queries in `json_query` are returning you two lists, so you do want to use the [`first` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.first).

Last, but not least, those two values are still going to return you some string, so you do want to use the [`int` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.int).

```
"{{ (ansible_facts | json_query('mounts[*].size_available') | first | int) / (ansible_facts | json_query('mounts[*].size_total') | first | int) * 100 }}"
```